# ¿Cómo centrar una imagen encima de un texto?

Tags: html, imagen

Tengo unos iconos que quiero colocar centrados encima de un texto pero no consigo que queden bien encima. Adjunto imagen de cómo me han quedado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que me quedara centrado decidí utilizar una tabla con 1 fila y 4 columnas. Como se observa en la imagen superior el texto queda centrado en la celda correspondiente, mientras que el icono está alineado a la izquierda.

Adjunto el código que estoy utilizando en esta tabla.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
.t1 {
  color: #624662;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.t2 {
  color: #fc8e04;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 600px wide, make the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .column {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <img src="URL" class="middle" width="50" height="50"></div>
      <div class="t1"><b>Plazas de movilidad</b></div>
      <div class="t2">+350</div>
      <div class="t1">Más de 350 plazas anuales de movilidad internacional </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <div style="text-align: center">
        <img src="URL" class=" middle " width="50 " height="50 "></div>
      <div class="t1 "><b>Países</b></div>
      <div class="t2 ">37</div>
      <div class="t1 ">37 países con más de 120 universidades colaboradoras. </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column ">
      <div style="text-align: center "><img src="URL " class="middle " width="50 " height="50 "></div>
      <div class="t1 "><b>Dobles titulaciones</b></div>
      <div class="t2 ">25</div>
      <div class="t1 ">Posibilidad de obtener dobles titulaciones en 25 universidades. </div>
    </div>

    <div class="column "></div>
    <div style="text-align: center "><img src="URL " class="middle " width="40 " height="40 "></div>
    <div class="t1 "><b>Porcentaje</b></div>
    <div class="t2 ">+80%</div>
    <div class="t1 ">Más del 80% de los alumnos se van a su primera opción.</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Mi intención es que cada uno de los iconos quede centrado encima de su texto correspondiente. Por ejemplo, el planeta tierra quiero que esté centrado encima de "Plazas de movilidad". En este caso sería echar las imágenes hacia la derecha.

EDICIÓN 1: He añadido más detalle en el código adjunto. Dado que las direcciones de los iconos son muy largas las he modificado por la palabra url, para que resulte más sencillo.
EDICIÓN 2: Al ejecutar mi respuesta se obtienen los resultados, pero en mi web siguen apareciendo los iconos desplazados. Algunos usuarios (gracias!) me han indicado que es posible que otro CSS esté interfiriendo. En esa misma página, tengo un registro independiente con otro HTML y su correspondiente CSS. Yo entiendo que son ficheros separados. De todas formas, adjunto el código CSS del archivo html (un slider de fotos) superior al que me da problemas:

```
* {box-sizing:border-box}
 body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
  
.slideshow-container {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    horizontal-align: middle;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  position: relative;    
}
img {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
}
  
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 1170px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffc8e04;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fc8e04;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
    left:30%;
    top:80%;
    
}
  
.prev,
.next {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: -22px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    transition: .3s ease;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0
}

.next {
    right: -0px;
    <!--border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px-->
}

.prev {
    left: -0px;
    <!--border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px-->
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
    color: #fc8e04;
    background-color: white
}


.text {
    color: #fc8e04;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #337ab7
}

.dot {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: background-color .3s ease
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
    background-color: #fc8e04
}
/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

Comment: Si aún no tienes una clase en el div de los íconos, debes crearla y en el css alinearlos, si estás usando bootstrap podrías hacer directamente en el html, podría ser con "text-center" todo depende como lo tengas en tú código.

Comment: No veo en tú código publicado los íconos, por eso no puedo darte información concreta.

Comment: A mí con ese código la imagen me queda centrada con el resto de contenidos del `DIV` (la clase `middle` no está definida y no parece que la necesites tampoco).

Comment: @Joe he modificado el código adjunto para ofrecer más detalle.

Comment: @juanrpozo a mi me continúa saliendo como en la imagen adjunta. ¿Cómo debería definir la clase `middle`?

Comment: @Maititis Si ejecutas el código de la pregunta, se ve bien. Puede que haya otro CSS que esté afectando la imagen en tu página. Deberías compartirlo porque tal y como esta ahora el problema no se puede reproducir.

Comment: Coincido con älvaro, el código funciona, quizás tienes otro CSS que esté interfiriendo

Comment: Siii, tenéis razón @AlvaroMontoro y joe al ejecutarlo aquí sale correctamente y en otros sitios de prueba también, en cambio en la web en la que va colgado el html sigue apareciendo desplazado hacia la izquierda

Comment: En la misma página de la web tengo otro registro html, de un slider con imágenes, (yo entiendo que son totalmente independientes) y este tiene su CSS particular. ¿Podría interferir con esta parte?

Comment: Ya sé lo que pasa. En el archivo anterior defino ciertas características para img, ¿hay alguna forma de poner etiquetas diferentes a las imágenes?